# cannot able to create List of string in dart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am try to create a List of string

i need a list like `["9999999998","9876788667","8753578546"]`.

but what i get us `[9999999998,9876788667,8753578546]`

this is my list declaration

```
List<String> numbers = <String>[];
```

adding string to the list

```
numbers.add(numberController.text);
```

Comment: You *did* get a `List` of `String`s.  You're confused because if you call `print` on it, it will be printed as `[9999999998,9876788667,8753578546]`.  Calling `print` on a `List` calls `.toString()` on each element, and calling `.toString()` on a `String` will just return that `String`.  It won't add extra quotes around it if that's what you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Can you verify it by running `print(numbers[0].runtimeType);`

TextEditingController.text always gives you string even if you're typing numbers in your TextField Widget. Hence the list you have is actually a list of Strings.

Answer (score 0):

First, avoid to using `List<String> numbers = <String>[];`. Use `List<String> numbers = [];` or `var numbers = <String>[];` is enough.

Second, your code is looking fine, it type is `String` already, but dart console not print double quote `""` of a string. You can check the type by using `runtimeTupe`.

Example with dynamic list:

```dart
void main() {
  var numbers = <dynamic>[
    "123",
    123,
    123.2,
  ];
  
  numbers.forEach((e) {
    print("type of '$e' is '${e.runtimeType}'");
  });

  // --- Resutl
  type of '123' is 'String'
  type of '123' is 'int'
  type of '123.2' is 'double'
}
```

Example with your list:

```dart
void main() {
  var numbers = <String>["9999999998","9876788667","8753578546"];
  
  numbers.forEach((e) {
    print("type of '$e' is '${e.runtimeType}'");
  });

  // --- Resutl
  type of '9999999998' is 'String'
  type of '9876788667' is 'String'
  type of '8753578546' is 'String'
}
```

Comment: yeah it showing the element as string but when i got this list in nodejs it look like this [919361667266@c.us, 919361667266@c.us]